# How to wait for webview.post to complete?

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, runnable

In the below code, `outside` is printed before `inside`. I want the order to be `inside` first and then `outside`. So how do I ensure that the `Runnable` is finished before the second `Log` is reached?

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("check", "inside");
    }
});

// some code needed here

Log.d("check", "outside");
```

Some code must be inserted where to comment is to achieve this.

**EDIT:** I am doing all the work in a background service.

*[P.S.: Those who are curious as to why I am doing this, it is so because unless I add the `webview.post`, I keep getting the following error: "All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.". Anyway, this shouldn't affect you from answering the question.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

webView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("check", "inside");
        latch.countDown();
    }
});

// some code needed here
latch.await();

Log.d("check", "outside");
```

However, you wouldn't want to use `latch.await()` on the UI thread, as that's a blocking method. If you wanted to run this on the UI thread it would be best to replace `latch.countDown()` with a call to a callback method, which would in turn run `Log.d("check", "outside")`.

Comment: I am doing all my work on a background service. I forgot to mention it in the question. Will it work with that? Thanks.

Comment: This `CountDownLatch` setup should definitely work inside a background service.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. Also, "webView.post" is never called. I read somewhere that it needs to be called from the UI Thread.

Comment: 'webView.post` doesn't need to be called from the UI thread - it just makes the runnable inside it execute on the UI thread itself. The above code works if I wrap it inside, for example, `Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {...});`. I'm not sure why it's failing to be called in your case, maybe some more of your code would give more context?